# Как убрать hover на мобильных устройствах?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, ios9

Тестирую на устройстве с ios 9 и при клике срабатывает стиль hover. Как сделать, чтобы стиль наведения не срабатывал на мобильных устройствах?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Проверяем наличие тач-события и вешаем соответствующий класс, если это десктоп
2. Ховер-стили пишем с каскадом, например: `.no-touch a:hover { color: red }`

```js
if (('ontouchstart' in window) || window.DocumentTouch && document instanceof DocumentTouch) {
  console.log('this is a touch device');
} else {
  console.log('this is not a touch device');
  document.body.classList.add('no-touch');
}
```

```css
body.no-touch {
  background-color: blue;
}

a {
  color: yellow
}

.no-touch a:hover {
  color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">ссылка для примера</a>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам ) !

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй поместить hover-стили в медиа-запрос на [`pointer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/pointer)

```
@media (pointer: fine) {
```

Хотя такой вариант попрортит стили в браузерах, т. к. много где не поддерживается.

Лучше выставить стили без hover для `:hover` в

```
@media (pointer: coarse) {
```